# How can I await for state to be set if it doesn't return a promise?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to set state to my setStockInfo hook and wait for the for it to be set before I run props.onInitialSet(). I tried passing setStockInfo as a dependency in the useEffect, but getting no luck. I need the information from stockInfo before I set to the global store. Is there a way I can use a callback since useState doesn't return a promise? The error returning is "cannot read property symbol of undefined" from the props.initialSet()

```
function TopStocks(props) {
const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([]);

const symbols = ["AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOGL", "TSLA"];
let temp = [];


 useEffect(() => {
    fetchSymbols();
    props.onInitialSet(
      stockInfo[2].symbol,
      stockInfo[2].percentage,
      stockInfo[2].close
    );
  }, [setStockInfo]);



async function fetchSymbols() {
    for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
      await fetch(
        `api${symbols[i]}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((allStocks) => {
          console.log(allStocks);
          try {
            let metaDataEntries = allStocks["Meta Data"];
            let symbol = metaDataEntries["2. Symbol"].toUpperCase();
            let pastDataEntries = allStocks["Time Series (Daily)"];
            let pastDataValues = Object.values(pastDataEntries);
            let mostRecentValue = pastDataValues[0];
            let x = Object.values(mostRecentValue);
            let open = parseFloat(x[0]).toFixed(2);
            let high = parseFloat(x[1]).toFixed(2);
            let low = parseFloat(x[2]).toFixed(2);
            let close = parseFloat(x[3]).toFixed(2);
            let colorToSend;

            let percentage = close - open;
            if (percentage < 0) {
              colorToSend = "red";
            } else {
              colorToSend = "rgb(30, 216, 139)";
            }
            let result = parseFloat(percentage).toFixed(2);

            temp.push({
              symbol: symbol,
              high: high,
              low: low,
              close: close,
              open: open,
              percentage: result,
              color: colorToSend,
            });
          } catch {
            console.log("surpassed the limit of 4 requests in under a minute");
          }
        });
    }

    setStockInfo(temp);
  }


}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {

onInitialSet: (symbol, percentage, price) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "INITIALSET",
        value: {
          price: price,
          symbol: symbol,
          percentage: percentage,
        },
      });
    }



}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TopStocks);
```

Comment: You can change fetchSymbols to return a promise: `Promise.all(symbols.map(
      symbol=>{
        fetch('api${symbol}')
        .then(res=>res.json())
      }
    ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stockInfo` is the value that will change, not the state setter. Inside the `useEffect`, check to see if the array has been populated:

```
// Run once, on mount:
useEffect(fetchSymbols, []);
// Run after fetchSymbols finishes:
useEffect(() => {
  if (stockInfo.length) {
    props.onInitialSet(
      stockInfo[2].symbol,
      stockInfo[2].percentage,
      stockInfo[2].close
    );
  }
}, [stockInfo]);
```

You should also put a `try`/`catch` around the `await fetch` so you can catch possible network errors.

Comment: I thought by passing stockInfo instead of setStockInfo, that it would cause an infinite loop? Thanks btw

Comment: If `onInitialSet` results in a change to something that eventually causes a change to `stockInfo`, yes, but that wasn't specified in the question. If that's an issue and you want `onInitialSet` to be called only once, on render, you could have another stateful variable like `initialSetDone` that you set to true and check inside the callback.

Comment: @Jayg713, fetching once will only update `stockInfo` once so it won't cause an infinite loop. Unless as mentioned by CertainPerformance which is an anti-pattern since you have multiple sources of truth.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `useEffect` runs **after** every render, the fetched `stockInfo` is not reflected *until after the current rendering process*.

Thus, `stockInfo` is undefined when passed to `onInitialSet`.

To solve this, follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-principles/) by simply splitting to two effects:

1. First effect is to fetch symbols
2. Set initial set

```
const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([]);

// First effect: to fetch
useEffect(async () => {
  let temp;

  for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
      await fetch(`api${symbols[i]}`);
      // TODO: add rest of code
  }

  setStockInfo(temp);
}, []);

// 2nd effect: call onInitialSet
useEffect(() => {
  if (stockInfo.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  props.onInitialSet(
    stockInfo[2].symbol,
    stockInfo[2].percentage,
    stockInfo[2].close
  );
}, [stockInfo]);
```